# Create an e-mail in Sent-folder

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'd like to know whether I'm able to create an item in the Sent-folder of an Exchange account.

The reason is that I have an application which sends an e-mail by itself and doesn't cooperate with the Exchange server directly. But the Exchange server shall notice that.

Via a webservice I want to create that item in the Sent-folder so if an user checks his Exchange account he'll see which e-mails he sent.

Is it possible to create an item in the Sent-folder?
Or can I move a draft to the Sent-folder in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Miscrosoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage` you can do `message.Save(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems);`

Comment: Thanks to you! Much easier than I thought.